# Double foldertree in one webpage

Tags: php, jquery, html

I downloaded "The simple folder tree" from [Techlister.com](http://techlister.com/php/simple-folder-tree-with-php-and-jquery/1231/) (View the demo [here](http://techlister.com/filetree/)). With that code I tried to create a source and a target folder tree in one webpage to select a source and a target folder for a converting program. You can download this code in a zipfile from [this location](https://www.renetta.nl/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/foldertree.zip).

My problem is that if I select the source folder, the path is filled in both the "Source" input field and the "Target" input field (and the submit button). If I select the target folder nothing happens.

Can you help me to fill the source and target input fields by clicking the folder in the folder trees like
[this example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FuDuc.png)?
Many thanks in advance!
Rene

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue myself:

I gave the input fields an ID, i.e.:

```
<input type="text" name="source" id="source"
<input type="text" name="target" id="target"
```

and in the javascript I referenced to that input field:

```
$( "source" ).val( source_folder );
$( "target" ).val( target_folder );
```

That did the trick.